# Создание подкаталогов в Python, модернизация кода

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток знатоки.
Написал так код в Python где создаются подкаталоги в определенным каталоге.

```
import os
path = r'H:\Sort\SDJ'
os.chdir(path)
os.mkdir('LOGI')
os.chdir(os.path.join(path, 'LOGI'))
os.mkdir('PREV')
os.mkdir('PROD')
os.listdir
```

Хочу написать или смодорнизировать мой код.  Абы подкаталоги создавались где название каталога начинается ABC.......
Будут у вас какие идеи ? Прошу  мне подсказать как можно мне сделать.
Заранее Спасибо

Comment: подкаталоги должны начинаться с ABC или они должны быть созданы в каталоге с "ABC", или рядом с ним?

Comment: Подкаталоги должны быть в каталоге с ABC__.  Например есть катало ABC_цифры подкаталог создается Logi-->PREV-->PROD.  Простите начинаю только учить Python.

Comment: Как бы ищет название главных каталогов которые начиются с ABC_ и там хочет создать эти подкаталоги

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```py
import os

a = os.listdir()

for i in a:
    if "ABC__" in i:
        print(i)
        os.chdir(i)

os.mkdir('LOGI')
```

Через os.listdir() вы находите каталог и дальше уже пишите в него.
Можно не заходить в каталоги с создавать папки из текущего `os.mkdir(i+"\\"+'LOGI')`. Но лучше посмотрите в сторону `pathlib` для создания путей.

Comment: Cпасибо вам огромное за этот пример